# side-effects in functional programming (racket)

Tags: functional-programming, racket

I want to better understand the side-effects in a functional language like Racket.

1. Racket is not a purely functional language, right? In the book it defines side-effect as:

> if it influences subsequent computation (and ultimately program output) in any way other than by returning a value for use in the surrounding context.

According to the definition, I think `define`, `set!` or `displayln` should be side-effects. Then what about `let`?

2. What is the easiest way to distinguish what is side effects..

Comment: If an entire program had no side-effects it would do nothing. In "purely functional" languages like Haskell, pure functions are used to describe what is performed by I/O operations (which have side effects).

Comment: What do you mean with "what about let"? In what way do you see `let` having a side effect?

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy, that is not correct, a program can still have a _result_. And the trick with I/O in Haskell that this result _describes_ an I/O interaction, but the computation itself does not perform it.

Comment: @AndreasRossberg blah, stupid me, of course it could generate a result. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are various possible definitions, but a common and enlightening one is that a side effect is anything that makes the *order of evaluation* observable. That is, a program is *pure* (free of side effects) if you can simplify any of its subexpressions, in any order, merely by substituting definitions, without changing the outcome of the program. In particular, you can always replace a variable with its definition, without evaluating that first.

This implies that I/O, mutable state and exceptions are side effects, as one would expect. Strictly speaking, it even implies that non-termination is an effect -- and while that may sound strange at first, it is exactly what you want in the case of dependently-typed languages, for example.

Comment: Thank you! But could you give me examples? I am still confused with "simplifying subexpressions" you mentioned or the sentence, "you can always replace a variable with its definition , without evaluating that first." In Racket, `define` is a side effect while `let` is not. I want to know clearly why this is the true.

Comment: @HAruMOmo, `define` introduces mutable state, because you can change the definition later (via another define for the same identifier). Accordingly, it matters _when_ you use the identifier. Not so with `let`: if you bind some x to a value V with `let`, then it is immutable, and using that x will always result in V. Consequently, replacing all uses of x in the program with V directly would not change the outcome of the program (assuming V itself is pure as well).

Comment: What does same identifier mean exactly?

Comment: Interesting aside: the property of being able to evaluate expressions in any order is called the [Church Rosser property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church%E2%80%93Rosser_theorem)